# LAN transfer with windows explorer and xcopy = unresponsive network

Tags: networking

I have a Linksys E2000 router with 2 gbit nodes connected and a gbit switch that has 3 nodes connected. After transferring small or large files to/from any nodes for about 30 seconds at 30-60 MB\s the whole network becomes unresponsive until the transfer is over. If I use fastcopy or teracopy the transfer is a little faster and the network remains responsive as expected. I have tried forcing 100mbit (11 MB\s transfer), Windows 7 and 8.1 host\client and 100 mbit switch/router with no changes. I think it's something related to windows 7/8 system buffer. Any idea what's going on and if there's a fix?